# How do I recover from a disk read error (fread failed)?

Tags: bitcoind, error

My full node daemon (bitcoind) crashed due to a disk read failure. The error is as follows:

[image]

"Deserialize or I/O error - CAutoFile::read: fread failed" etc.

How do I recover from this error? I don't want to have to download the whole database again.

Comment: I had read failures myself in the course of last week. I think it is important for you to uncover the source of the problem: is it a bug in `bitcoind`, a bug in the operating system, a corrupted file system (which may happen very easily when systems are shutdown abruptly), is it a hardware problem with a flaw in the hard disk? In my case, the OS did inform me of inconsistent file system, tried to repair things, but it got worse and worse. I then reinstalled the whole OS + `bitcoind` and the problem reappeared. In the end I had to change hardware, reinstall OS + `bitcoind`.

Comment: The good news is: `v0.14.0` is mightly quick compared to previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a related question here: [When should I use -reindex-chainstate and when -reindex](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60709/when-should-i-use-reindex-chainstate-and-when-reindex) <-- Read this for more info.

You could try

> -reindex-chainstate

If that doesn't work then try

> -reindex

Quoted from the linked question:

> You should use -reindex only when you were running in pruning mode, or if you suspect the blocks on disk are actually corrupted. Otherwise, when you only suspect corruption of the chainstate (which is far more likely), use -reindex-chainstate.