# How to use -reindex

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, reindex

I am working on creating a [Pathing Guide for macOS Installation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/26778). The

IN:

```
./bitcoind
```

OUT:

```
2023-01-02T01:26:12Z : You need to rebuild the database using -reindex to go back to unpruned mode.  This will redownload the entire blockchain.
Please restart with -reindex or -reindex-chainstate to recover.
```

A good overview of when to use `-reindex` is provided on [StackExchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60709/when-should-i-use-reindex-chainstate-and-when-reindex). However, there is no documentation or instruction explaining what `-reindex` is or how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In the process of writing the question, I discovered the answer solving the problem:

```
./bitcoind -reindex
```